# Getting the value of a specific element from a different row in gnuplot

Tags: scripting, graph, plot, gnuplot

Using gnuplot 4.2, is it possible to obtain the value of a specific column/row and use that value somehow?

For example, let's say my datafile contains the following

```
#1  2
7  13
5  11
23 17
53 12
```

For a simple plot where column 1 is the x axis and column 2 is the y axis I would:-

```
plot 'datafile' using 1:2
```

What I'm trying to do is to normalize the all data in column 2 by the first element in that column (13). Is there a way to do this in gnuplot itself (i.e., without resorting to a scripting language or something to preprocess the data first)?

Cheers

Answer (score 7):

Using the running averages demo, I managed to achieve a plot normalized to the first value of the second column.

The `base` variable is used to store the reference value, and the `first` function initializes `base` on the first row.

```
first(x) = ($0 > 0 ? base : base = x)
plot file.dat u 1:(first($2), base/$2)
```

It should be mentioned that this was not done using gnuplot 4.2.

**Edit:** Updated using Christoph's advice.

Comment: Nice, +1. To be more general one could check for the row number being 0 for setting the `base` value: `first(x) = ($0 > 0 ? base : base = x)`.

Comment: This solution assumes, however, that the file does not contain single or double empty lines. If you have empty lines you will have the condition `$0==0` several times.

Answer (score 1):

If your base value (e.g. 13) is in the first row of your data set, you should be able to do what you want using the CVS version of gnuplot.

Have a look at the [running averages demo](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.3/data_feedback.html). Along those lines, you could write a custom function that stores the base value in a custom variable when called for the first time, and returns that variable on subsequent calls.

(Since that demo is listed for the CVS version only, I assume the required functionality is not available in the current release version.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stats` command to get the first value of the second column and store it in the `reference` variable as shown below,

```
stats 'datafile' using (reference=$2) every ::0::0 nooutput
```

You can replace `$2` with any other column you want. The zeros in `every ::0::0` implies the first entry of the column and you can also use `every ::n::n` to get the nth entry of the column. `nooutput` is used to avoid the cluttered console.

You can then get normalized plot using,

```
plot 'datafile' using 1:($2/reference)
```

Comment: Just for completeness: in case you might have single or double empty lines in your data you'd better use:  `stats 'datafile' u (reference=$2) index 0 every ::0:0:0:0 nooutput`, otherwise you might get unexpected results.

Answer (score -1):

ad a new column full of 13, then use:

plot 'datafile' using 1:($2/$3)